# Reflecting into a class without FQCN

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

Is it possible to reflect into a class without knowing the fully qualified class name?

e.g. instead of this...

```php
(new ReflectionClass(\App\Modules\Companies\Models\Company::class));
```

...something like this?

```php
(new ReflectionClass('Company'));
```

Comment: You want it to find a class named "Company" and show you it? Namespaces are important, as above you want the Model Company what if you had component named Company?

Comment: Yes, I have an array which has things like 'company', 'user', 'form' and need to instantiate a new class from those using reflection to look at the particular item in the array. The items all correspond to classes in the application.

I have currently got a lookup table to match the item in the array with the FQCN but if we have additional items to the array later on, the lookup table would also need to be updated. Seems counterintuitive.

Comment: You can't. Even with a use statement in place, you couldn't do it for a namespaced class. FQCN must be supplied.

Comment: Here's a [very old comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php#89926), but having tested its claims, I find that it is still valid.

Comment: This points out that where ever are those class names, they need to be replace by their full path (namespace and class).

Comment: FYI, Laravel has a feature called Aliases/Facades, maybe it will help.